# System.Net.Socket call: AddressFamily has unknown value 0x1d

Tags: java, sockets, java-native-interface, socketexception

I'm trying to access a CAN port on a system running Android.

In Java JNI, I can call:

```
    int s=socket(29 /*PF_CAN*/, 3 /*SOCK_RAW*/ , 1 /*CAN_RAW*/);
```

and everything works. But I need to make it run in Unity, C#.

In C#, I try:

```
    Socket sock = new Socket((AddressFamily)29 , (SockType)3 , (ProtocolType)1);
```

and get a SocketException

ADB:

```
01-01 04:48:38.183 1568-1587/com.xxx.xxx W/mono: System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily has unknown value 0x1d

01-01 04:48:38.253 1568-1587/com.xxx.xxx I/Unity: SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
                                                            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (AddressFamily family, SocketType type, ProtocolType proto) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                                            at CANPortScript.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I found the equivalent enum values for 29, 3, and 1 as valid Socket() parameters, but I still get the Exception.  29 is the enum AddressFamily.Max.

Any way to force it even though it doesn't recognize 29 as a valid AddressFamily?  Alternately, any better way to access this?

Comment: .NET does not support CAN in sockets. You can't just type-cast arbitrary numbers to enums, you have to use the values that are defined in the enums. But `AddressFamily` and `ProtocolType` do not have any entries for CAN (for the socket type, use `SocketType.Raw` instead of hard-coding 3). You will have to use a different solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CAN bus communication with System.Net.Sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714576/).

Comment: Actually, my my custom OS build supports it.  Maybe a misunderstanding of all the parts involved - I am running a custom Android build that uses sockets as an interface on an application level.  Straight java JNI works in this way.  Now I am working with Unity that exports a .net application to Android.  I believe there is a way to access CAN via sockets in the same way as java JNI.

Comment: Not via .NET, there isn't. CAN is simply not accessible in .NET's socket interface. You would likely have to drop down to the JNI layer directly in order to do what you are looking for.